# Sample with Mysql with dynamic table name

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tell me please. It is necessary to make a selection with the database at which the name of the table, from which the sample is made, is formed based on the table prefix and the data that is extracted from the table.

Tables: Sites, Chats and Chat_ID (tables with correspondence).

I need to get the site id and the number of unread from this site. I do this:

```
SELECT
  s.id AS id,
 (SELECT
   COUNT(*)
  FROM
    HOW TO ET TABLE NAME? AS ch
  WHERE
    ch.chat_id = c.id AND
    status = 0 AND
    type = 'CLIENT'
  ) AS unread
FROM
  site AS s
  LEFT JOIN chat AS c ON
    c.site_id = s.id AND
    c.operator_id = s.user_id
WHERE
  s.user_id = 1;
```

The name of the table consists of the prefix and id of the site - chat_1.

Maybe it's not right - do not throw slippers)

Comment: your question is quite confusing

Comment: you would have to use dynamic sql...

Comment: Can you make question bit clear. Add some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the tables are not parameterizable at the SQL level. Only literal values can be parameterized.

In your case you need to use different tables based on the parameter values. To do this you need to **build your SQL as a string** in your programming language (Java, PHP, Python, etc.) concatenating parts to assemble the table names and the rest of the query.

You don't have other solution.